# Sorting lines based on certain digit pattern

Tags: awk, grep, perl, sort, netstat

Assume I have a text file with the following lines:

```
192.168.1.1.55555
192.168.1.1.55555
192.168.1.1.5555
192.168.1.1.555
192.168.1.1.55
192.168.1.1.55
192.168.1.1.5
8.8.8.8.4433
8.8.8.8.443
8.8.8.8.443
8.8.8.8.25
192.168.1.2.99
```

as you can see above, each line will have the following pattern (I couldn't write all possible variations since there are 9.9599603594104e+16 possible lines)

```
[number composed of 1 to 3 digits].[number composed of 1 to 3 digits].[number composed of 1 to 3 digits].[number composed of 1 to 3 digits].[number composed of 1 to 5 digits]
```

I want a grep/sort statement that counts the lines where the first four numbers matched and print that count.

The expected output for the example above is:

```
192.168.1.1 7
8.8.8.8 4
192.168.1.2 1
```

Side notes:

1. I'm trying to sort `netstat` output, the lines I'm dealing with in reality are IP addresses followed by port numbers.
2. My unix system where this needs be executed doesnt have `uniq` or `cut` tools, it has operating system from some networking vendor which is built on freebsd.

one of the commenters on this post suggested to use:

```
awk -F. '{c[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4]++} END {for (i in c) print i, c[i]}'
```

which seems to work well.

Comment: I'd suggest you post the solution you just added to your question as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cut -d'.' -f1-4 file | uniq -c
      7 192.168.1.1
      4 8.8.8.8
      1 192.168.1.2
```

or if the input isn't sorted as shown in your example and/or the order of output columns matters:

```
$ cut -d'.' -f1-4 file | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}'
192.168.1.1 7
192.168.1.2 1
8.8.8.8 4
```

Comment: can same result be achieved without using cut and uniq? the system where this needs be executed doesn't have those too

Comment: Sure, there's many ways to do it but if you don't have mandatory POSIX tools like cut and uniq then you'll have to update your question to tell us what environment you're running in and exactly which tools you do have. It's extremely hard to believe, though, that your system has awk, grep, perl, and sort (the tools you tagged) but not cut and uniq.

Comment: @EdMorton I was going to suggest `awk -F. '{c[$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4]++} END {for (i in c) print i, c[i]}' file` but I assume I'm missing something else you would have mentioned that?

Comment: @steeldriver I actually have something a bit different (and more efficient) in mind but I just don't want to suggest anything else until the OP tells us which tools they really have available. If they don't have cut and uniq then I'm having a hard time believing that they have grep, sort, awk and perl!

Comment: Thank you for your replies, i updated the question, i have also wrote that the suggestion from @steeldriver seems to work well.

Comment: Then post it as an answer and accept it.